# XML schema two-level key/keyref constraints

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Given the following xml:

```
<root>
  <families>
     <family familyname="Flintstone">
         <member name="Fred"/>
         <member name="Wilma"/>
     </family>
     <family familyname="Rubble">
         <member name="Barney"/>
         <member name="Betty"/>
         <member name="Bamm-Bamm"/>
     </family>
  </families>
  <employees>
     <employee name="Fred" familyname="Flintstone"/>
  <employees>
</root>
```

Is it possible to build a key/keyref constraint in the xsd to verify the validity of empployee?

The following does not work for key (the keyref is straigt forward):

```
<xs:key name="Individuals">
    <xs:selector xpath="./families/family/member"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    <xs:field xpath="../@familyname"/>
</xs:key>
```

Is there a valid alternative?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible as described. I assume a "valid alternative" is one that achieves your intent, even if it involves changes to XML.

In which case, simply add a new mandatory attribute to the member (@key as an example) element. It means you should drop name + familyname from employee, and add key instead.

It'll feel more like a "database"... Benefits:

- smaller size
- normalized design
- key/keyref easy to do
- after all, familyname + member/@name may not always be unique. With keys, you wouldn't have this problem since you're really identifying a member (not a person, since same person may be involved in two different families, son in one, husband in another one).

I realize that your illustration is a mockup of a real world scenario, hence my last benefit may not be relevant in your real case. Still, this is the kind of thinking one should apply.